# http.client.HTTPException: got more than 100 headers

Tags: python, http, exception

Since google did not find anything regarding error "http.client.HTTPException: got more than 100 headers", I created this question.

```
>>> import http.client as h
>>> conn = h.HTTPConnection("www.coursefinders.com")
>>> conn.request("HEAD","/")
>>> conn.getresponse();
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1148, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 376, in begin
    self.headers = self.msg = parse_headers(self.fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 267, in parse_headers
    raise HTTPException("got more than %d headers" % _MAXHEADERS)
http.client.HTTPException: got more than 100 headers
```

What does this exception mean and how should I properly handle this type of error? Site works OK in browser.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a solution that doesn't involve changing library's py files:

```
import httplib  # or http.client if you're on Python 3
httplib._MAXHEADERS = 1000
```

Just put that at the top of your code

Answer (score 4):

change the value of "_MAXHEADERS" to 1000 or 10000 in C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py

Comment: I would suggest against modifying Python libraries. How would you deploy it later on? Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38815673/126574

Answer (score 3):

I was going to suggest using `requests`, but it's implemented using http.client and fails for the same reason.  To verify whether the problem was in the library or the server, I tried a telnet session, and the results resembled:

```
Trying 91.250.81.121...
Connected to www.coursefinders.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD / HTTP\1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 08:35:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2bnr4dpa4e90r2lmbv01smu1b6; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: c_id=496cc5d32486ac8d944e971ad6ec9eb3649ab23cs%3A3%3A%22235%22%3B; expires=Tue, 15-Apr-2014 08:35:54 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: wc=1; expires=Thu, 09-Apr-2015 08:35:54 GMT
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
[... Many Set-Cookie commands omitted ...]
Set-Cookie: login=-1; path=/
Cache-Control: max-age=1, private, must-revalidate
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

So it looks like their server is misconfigured and is spewing out lots of superfluous Set-Cookie headers.

There doesn't seem to be any way to configure `httplib` to accept large numbers of headers.  I've tried searching for alternative HTTP libraries that aren't implemented using `httplib` but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Still, header size in your output is not even close to 100 lines. This error is weird.

Comment: I indicated that I'd omitted a lot of the output as it was redundant.  I still haven't had any luck finding a library that doesn't depend on httplib.client.

Answer (score 0):

one OSX I added this to my code

```
import httplib as http_client
```

Then debug the script to find where the library was being loaded from.  in my case it was

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py
```

I then editing the limit as per Felix's post

```bash
sudo vim /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py
```