# How to fix ansible uri module error got more than 100 headers?

Tags: ansible

I am making a request to publish a plugin to on vmware with the ansible `uri` module:

```yaml
- name: Enable the App Launchpad plugin if it is set
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ URL }}/cloudapi/extensions/ui/{{ plugin_id }}/tenants/publish"
    method: "POST"
    status_code: 200
    body_format: json
    return_content: yes
    body:
      - name: "{{ org_name }}"
        id: "{{ org_uuid }}"
    headers:
      Authorization: "{{ vdc_token }}"
```

However I am getting a fatal error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "content": "", "elapsed": 0, 
"msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: An unknown error occurred: got more than 100 headers",
"redirected": false, "status": -1,
"url": ".../cloudapi/extensions/ui/urn:vcloud:uiPlugin:b92bf.../tenants/publish"}
```

When I make a request diretly without ansible it works but it does have over 100 headers...

I do not have control of the amount of headers returned, so what can I do form the ansible playbook side?

Comment: I think you are hitting this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055378/http-client-httpexception-got-more-than-100-headers